# Music Visualizer for OMX Player

Tags: media

I'm trying to play msuic (mainly mp3 files) on the Raspberry Pi connected to my TV via HDMI. I'm using `9b52cee` binary of OMX Player from [here](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/). Audio playback is successful, but the TV screen is blank. Is there a visualizer plugin that can be integrated with OMX Player?

Comment: If you can find a way to get oxmplayer to work via pulseaudio, you could use a pulseaudio based visualizer, of which there seem to be a few (but you will probably have to compile those on the pi...).

Comment: @goldilocks: Thanks for the headsup, but getting pulseaudio to play nice seems to be a problem in itself.

Comment: It's a little user unfriendly IMO, yeah.  The issue with oxmplayer is that in order to use it with pulseaudio, oxmplayer must implement a client interface, which AFAICT it does not -- the only option is ALSA.  However, googling it looked like someone had gotten around this by using a fake ALSA card created by pulseaudio as a client.  If you can figure that out, you're set.  Except for compiling the visualizer, if there isn't one in your pi distro.  I'd add this to my own "Try TODO" list except that is already going to carry me well into the future, lol.

Comment: Here's an e.g. pulseaudio visualizer: http://projectm.sourceforge.net/ apparently used in XBMC.

Comment: @goldilocks: Thanks again for the pointers. I've gotten to the stage where pulseaudio works by following answers to [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/639/how-to-get-pulseaudio-running) question (yet to try system-wide mode, but the sample `.wav` plays fine). Will try the fake ALSA card next. :)